# change storage engine from InnoDB to MYISAM in WAMP Server

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have installed in windows 7 WAMP Server.  I want to change storage engine from InnoDB to MYISAM I search on google but I had not found anything

Here is content of my.ini file:

http://pastebin.com/AdW6JT8P

THANK YOU TO ALL!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to my.cnf:

```
default_storage_engine         = MYISAM
```